# Getting "Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM" with intern/saucelabs

Tags: intern, saucelabs

I'm just starting out with intern/saucelabs. Whenever I try a remote test, I'm getting `Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM.`

My intern.js has

```
environments: [
    { browserName: 'firefox', version: '28'},
],
tunnel: 'SauceLabsTunnel',
tunnelOptions: {
   username: 'foo',
   accessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
},
```

Execution log

```
$ intern-runner config=theintern/intern-sauce.js
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
**********************************************************
A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1283) is available!
Download it here:
https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3-linux.tar.gz
**********************************************************
Started scproxy on port 44275.
Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
Tunnel ID: 6586b9012ca2424b8ecd6bd6970e996c
Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
Remote tunnel host is: maki76026.miso.saucelabs.com
Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
Cleaning up.
Finished! Deleting tunnel.
Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM.
Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM.
  at reject  <../../../../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:353:17>
  at readStartupMessage  <../../../../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:381:12>
  at <../../../../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:434:12>
  at Array.some  <native>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <../../../../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:428:21>
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit  <events.js:117:20>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <_stream_readable.js:746:14>
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit  <events.js:92:17>
  at emitReadable_  <_stream_readable.js:408:10>
  at emitReadable  <_stream_readable.js:404:5>
```

In case it's significant, I'm currently on the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the most common issues folks run into with Sauce Connect are related to firewall and proxy settings. Please ensure that 443 is open between Sauce Connect and *.saucelabs.com. If a proxy server is used to route traffic on your network Sauce Connect supports proxy servers by passing the `--pac` or `–p` flag.

Please download the latest version of Sauce Connect from https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/ and start the client with all the necessary flags (a full list is available on the aforementioned page). If this version does not work please start Sauce Connect passing the `-v` flag, this will generate a verbose log file which will help Sauce Labs diagnose connectivity issues.

Comment: thx Michael. I actually jumped ship to Protractor (which worked first time, so not a firewall issue).