# Sauce connect using local proxy

Tags: http-proxy, saucelabs

I want all traffic to pass over proxy on my local machine. 
[image: scheme]

I have my proxy on `localhost:8888`
I tried:

```
sc -u <user_name> -k <key> -p localhost:8888
```

As it mentioned here [“Getting Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM” with intern/saucelabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711566/getting-error-failed-to-connect-to-tunnel-vm-with-intern-saucelabs) I tried to pass `-p` and `--pac`, but it didn't help me. 
This [documentation](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy+Configuration) page, that probably could have solved all my problems, is inaccessible due to some reason.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: `localhost` refers to the local machine. It looks like you're telling sauce to connect to the local machine (local for them, which is remote for you, not the machine you're working on). You'll need to get your local IP and specify it rather than localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sc -u <user_name> -k <key> -p 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Solved the problem

Comment: How to connect if the local proxy server is authentication based ?